# Использование нескольких типов пользователей в ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

В приложении должно присутствовать несколько типов учётных записей пользователей и у каждой должен быть свой набор полей. Одним из вариантов я вижу создание иерархии наследования:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public IImage AvatarImage { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class StudentUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public TeachingType TeachingType { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст я вижу таким:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TeacherUser> TeacherUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentUser> StudentUsers { get; set; }             
}
```

Есть ли способ научить Identity работать с этой иерархией и возвращать сущность пользователя нужного мне типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity в вашем случае использует *самый обычный* Entity Framework для хранения учетных записей пользователей - а Entity Framework всегда имел такую возможность.

Только контекст вы привели неправильный.

Независимо от способа хранения, `DbSet` должен быть один на иерархию и в нем должен храниться базовый класс.

А способов хранения - три:

1. `Table per Hierarchy` (TPH) - все свалено в одну таблицу.
2. `Table per Type` (TPT) - на каждый класс по таблице, их первичные ключи объединены отношениями вида 1 - (0..1).
3. `Table per Concrete class` (TPC) - по таблице на каждый неабстрактный класс. Но DbSet при этом все равно один!

Для создания БД первого типа просто добавьте `DbSet` с базовым типом в контекст - все потомки будут свалены в ту же таблицу автоматически.

Если вам больше нравится второй тип - добавьте потомкам атрибут `Table`. Или перегрузите метод `OnModelCreating`, указав там примерно следующее:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TeacherUser>().ToTable("TeacherUsers");
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentUser>().ToTable("StudentUsers");
```

Ну а если больше всего нравится третий тип - используйте вот такую конструкцию в том же методе:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TeacherUser>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("TeacherUsers");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentUser>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("StudentUsers");
});
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю `UserManager.FindAsync` всегда будет возвращать мне объект базового класса и через Identity я никак не смогу узнать настоящий тип пользователя?

Comment: Неправильно понимаете. EF всегда материализует объект требуемого типа - вам нужно только привести тип.

Answer (score 1):

Identity научить можно, но вот возвращаться вам всегда будет IUser.

Я бы рекомендовал отказаться от наследования и использовать композицию. Также, на мой взгляд, не нужно мешать identity и ваш domen.

Так у вас будет:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolUser
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public IImage AvatarImage { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
}

public class StudentUser : SchoolUser
{
    public TeachingType TeachingType { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}

public class TeacherUser : SchoolUser
{
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Кроме того, лучше всего будет написать свой "Identity" слой. Как это сделать, можете посмотреть здесь http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity